# Why the preloader gif stops working after refreshing 3-4 times

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, preloader

When I try refreshing the my html 3-4 times the preloader gif will work but after refreshing 3-4 times the preloader is shown but the gif is stucked you can run the code below and wait some time the gif will stuck.
please help me.
My codes for preloader are as follows:
HTML:

```js
 <script>/*====================================* Preloader Effect======================================*/ $(window).load(function() {   $(&quot;#status&quot;).fadeOut(&quot;slow&quot;);   $(&quot;#preloader&quot;).delay(350).fadeOut(&quot;slow&quot;); $(&#39;body&#39;).delay(350).css({&#39;overflow&#39;:&#39;visible&#39;}); 
   if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem( 'doNotShow' ) ) {
            sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', true );
            Preloader();
        } else {
           $ ('.loader, .preloader').hide();
        } 
   });</script>
```

```css
body {overflow: hidden; }#preloader {    position: fixed;    top: 0;    left: 0;    right: 0;    bottom: 0;    background-color: #ffffff;    z-index: 99999;}#status {    position: absolute;    left: 50%;    top: 50%;    background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QwTnWyZybZo/YApUJPvRhfI/AAAAAAAAAKs/9dvdximdULEwuLureqmvYrJwMBH9LLWugCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/cubeload_81544351%2B%25281%2529.gif);     background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: center;   width: 250px;    height: 250px;    margin: -120px 0 0 -120px;    padding: 0;}
```

```html
<div id='preloader'>
    <div id='status'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the inconvenience
I solved it myself the problem wasn't in the code I have not provided endless loop to the gif I was using.
I made it loop endless and the problem was solved.